# JavaFx How to set FXML loader for custom gui builder

Tags: javafx

I have a component on FXML file which contains the line:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="DataTableController">
```

I am trying to load the fxml in the controller:

```
public DataTableController() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("DataTable.fxml"));
}
```

I don't have a class that extends Application and I don't have a main method because I already have a window that is launched by another application (custom scene builder). So, I just want to show the AnchorPane on my window on a custom view component. I can do that using my controller, there is no problem. My problem is that I don't know how to load FXML when I don't use fx:root because when I change AnchorPane to fx:root, I can load FXML and set root and set controller and see the content of the fxml file on my window. However, then I have a problem that I can't set the contoller in the fxml file because it is a duplication of setting controller and if I don't set the controller in the fxml file, then I get an error because I have a button which needs the controler to be set.

So, what do I do? and when do we use fx:root and why? (I googled it and checked other SO entries but still it is not clear in my mind). Any suggestion to my problem and clear explanation with some examples about fx:root would be appreciated.

I am very new to JavaFX and SO, so please ask me kindly to clarify myself if I couldn't explain my problem well. Thanks for any help!

Edit: Changed java class as @fabian suggested and which I actually tried before
[and get this error as I mentioned above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z8Rm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I don't set the controller in the fxml file, then I get an error because I have a button which needs the controler to be set

Not true. As long as you set the controller instance of `FXMLLoader` before loading the fxml there shouldn't be an issue.

The recommended way of implementing this is the following:

```
public class DataTableController extends AnchorPane {

    public DataTableController() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DataTable.fxml"));

        // set this instance as root & controller
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);

        loader.load();
    }

    ...

}
```

```xml
<fx:root xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1"
         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
         type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane">
    ...
</fx:root>
```

Comment: I edited my answer with a screenshot. Can you please check it?

Comment: @Dawsey This is just NetBeans(?) complaining. It won't lead to an error in your JavaFX app though. The only drawback is that NetBeans can no longer check if the referenced members of the controller class exist in the editor...

Comment: Thank you, you are right! It is just NetBeans complaning, the button works. I just didn't try when I saw the red flag.